# Highcharts with data from mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter, highcharts

I'm using highcharts plugin to print stats in a codeigniter site.

Now I get the data from my database I manage it but when I print it inside highcharts nothing is printed.

This is my php code:

```
    $arr_point = array();
    $check_price = array();

    for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++){
        $sum = 0;
        $this->load->model('backend/Notification_model');
        $this->db->select('*,');
        $this->db->from('booking');     
        $query = $this->db->get();
        foreach ($query->result() as $row){
           $sum+=(float)$row->total_with_markup;
        }

        $arr_point[] = str_replace(',', '.', $sum);
    }
    $result = array();
    array_push($result,$arr_point);

    return(json_encode($result));
```

and this is my highchart configuration:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: $('#riepilogo option:selected').text()
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [
                    'Jan',
                    'Feb',
                    'Mar',
                    'Apr',
                    'May',
                    'Jun',
                    'Jul',
                    'Aug',
                    'Sep',
                    'Oct',
                    'Nov',
                    'Dec'
                ]
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Euro'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                    '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.2f} euro</b></td></tr>',
                footerFormat: '</table>',
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
            series: [ {
                name: $('#riepilogo options:selected').text(),
                data: "<?php echo json_decode($data_chart); ?>"
            }]
        });
});
```

if I print `json_decode($data_chart)` I get this:

```
Array
```

if I print `($data_chart` I get this:

```
[["0","297.23","74.41","65.57","2167.32","7649.77","2058.05","146.95","92.55","0","1754.72","0"]]
```

I have try to not use `json_encod`e, to use `json_decode`, nothing. Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: My question is clear I think "nothing is printed" highchart empty without line @AamirAfridi

Comment: remove the " of "<?php echo json_decode($data_chart); ?>"

Comment: If I remove it same thing, empty chart but results are present inside my variable @Dieter

Comment: Try printing  $data_chart[0] seems you have an array in array cuz of the double [[ ]] around your array

Comment: It prints "[", well you have right, how to solve it? @Dieter

Comment: I'll post the answer in a second.. Hold on EDIT: Do you always get 1 row in return or could it be possible to have more datarows?

Comment: I have always 12 rows to print one foreach month @Dieter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you create an array in your script:

```
 $arr_point = array();
```

Try returning just the array and delete:
$result = array();
    array_push($result,$arr_point);

and return $array_point;

Or try:

```
    $arr_point = "";
$check_price = array();

for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    $sum = 0;
    $this->load->model('backend/Notification_model');
    $this->db->select('*,');
    $this->db->from('booking');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $sum+=(float) $row->total_with_markup;
    }

    if($arr_point == ""){
        $arr_point .= "[";
    }

    if($arr_point != ""){
        $arr_poin .= ",";
    }

     $arr_point .= str_replace(',', '.', $sum);


}

$arr_point .= "]";


return $arr_point;
```

Comment: If I use your script and print the result I have this: 0[297.23[74.41[65.57[2167.32[7649.77[2058.05[146.95[92.55[0[1754.72[0]

Comment: Good morning! Sorry for the late answer, I edited my answer, there was a logical error in it.. plz try again :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains many injections, so I advice to print json inside your php file like:

```
echo json_encode($arr, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Then in javascript call `$.getJSON()` function and use it in highcahrts, skipping decoding / missing types of data.